# Video file (with alpha) as splash-screen?

Tags: animation, video, inno-setup, splash-screen

I'm searching for quite a while now for an extension for Inno Setup to use a video file, for example an AVI or maybe a .png sequence as a splash-screen for my installation (the usage of an alpha channel would be a HUGE plus but is not a must have).
There are several .dll's to use static pictures with a fade-in and fade-out but I couldn't find anything to use as video file for that purpose.

As far as I know, I can use any kind of .dll with Inno Setup. For example I can use the popular bass.dll for audio playback even though it has no "real" Inno support but Inno can call the functions of that .dll.

So is there any program out there that would allow me to do this?
Any tip in that direction would be very helpful.

Edit: This may be possible with Qt, I know you can make exactly those frame based splash-screens for your applications but I'm not sure if it's possible to use Qt with Inno Setup?

Comment: To your quote *if it's possible to use QT with Inno Setup*, it should be. There's a standalone qtmlClient.dll library, but its usage is quite complicated. +1 anyway, good question!

Comment: I also thought of using mplayer.dll or ffmpeg.dll but I have also no idea how I would use them in pascal script..

Comment: While a bit rudimentary, you could try using the ANIMATION control from the standard MS common controls library.  You'd probably want to make your own DLL file that both embeds the AVI resource you want to play along with the code to create the control and play it.

Comment: I got the video player on the wizard form just from script already but the problem is with codecs (what will be even though). I have installed some of the all in packs but the player says I have no codec for this type of video format. But about the formats, you will seriously need a standalone library or so, because you shouldn't rely on what codecs or players (in case of QuickTime) user has on his (or her) computer. I'll try to get the old school AVI file (no DivX or XVid) and test my solution, but I did it more for curiosity than serious usage (but it's part of Windows for a long time).

Comment: Could you give a copy of that script + dll that you are using?
The set of codecs directly available in windows is very limited. You could try to use Microsofts RLE even though it will have a huge size.

Comment: It's without DLL, just a pure script. It uses MCI (what is very, very old). I'll rollback my current changes and post it here, but as I said I couldn't figure out how to get the codec there. I can hear sound but no picture. And I've also tried to get it on the modal form but yet without success. I'll be right back with it ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have founded the [`Inno Media Player`](http://code.google.com/p/inno-media-player/) project which is able to embed the video and audio playback into the InnoSetup wizard. It is based on [`DirectShow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) technology and requires at least DirectX 9 to use.

Except [`built-in formats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it supports all DirectShow codecs, but you should consider that your target users doesn't need to have codecs for some exotic media formats and install them codec just because of the show at the installation startup would be an overkill and unfair to user.

About the transparency you wanted to have, if you find the codec that supports that, we can try to make the popup window transparent and let the DirectShow renderer draw on a layered window, but without the codec and a sample video I can't do nothing.

- the libraries with a sample script you may find in the source trunk or download it [`from here`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-media-player/downloads/list)
- I wrote a simple [`function reference`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-media-player/wiki/Reference) where you can find the function parameter descriptions

So to show a popup window with the video playback before the wizard form is displayed you can use the following:

***Please note, that Inno Media Player is a Unicode library, and so you can use it only with Unicode versions of InnoSetup, not with ANSI ones! There is no support for ANSI versions of InnoSetup...!***

```
[Setup]
AppName=Media Player Project
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Media Player Project

[Files]
Source: "MediaPlayer.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
const
  EC_COMPLETE = $01;

type
  TDirectShowEventProc = procedure(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer);

function DSPlayMediaFile: Boolean;
  external 'DSPlayMediaFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
function DSStopMediaPlay: Boolean;
  external 'DSStopMediaPlay@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
function DSInitializeVideoFile(FileName: WideString; WindowHandle: HWND;
  var Width, Height: Integer; CallbackProc: TDirectShowEventProc): Boolean;
  external 'DSInitializeVideoFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';

var
  VideoForm: TSetupForm;  

procedure OnMediaPlayerEvent(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer); 
begin
  if EventCode = EC_COMPLETE then
    VideoForm.Close;  
end;

procedure OnVideoFormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DSPlayMediaFile;
end;

procedure OnVideoFormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  DSStopMediaPlay;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Width: Integer;
  Height: Integer;
begin
  VideoForm := CreateCustomForm;
  VideoForm.Caption := 'Popup Video Window';
  VideoForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  VideoForm.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
  VideoForm.Position := poScreenCenter;
  VideoForm.OnShow := @OnVideoFormShow;
  VideoForm.OnClose := @OnVideoFormClose; 

  if DSInitializeVideoFile('d:\Video.avi', VideoForm.Handle, Width, 
    Height, @OnMediaPlayerEvent)
  then
  begin
    VideoForm.ClientWidth := Width;
    VideoForm.ClientHeight := Height;     
    VideoForm.ShowModal;
  end;    
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  DSStopMediaPlay;
end;
```

Hope that it helps!

Comment: Here is a simple sample video. It's an avi without any compression, it's basically bitmaps in an avi. It's a standard codec in windows and supported atleast since XP afaik.
This 7zip has 2 files, one with 8bit and one with 32bit if needed. They are pretty huge without compression but it has a compression ratio of about 3% with LZMA2.
http://www.mediafire.com/?ea123l1ua82kgsf

Comment: Sorry for all those posts, I always click the edit button too late..
Does the user need the DirectX 9 redistributable or just a GPU with DirectX9 support?

Comment: Cleaning time :-) I've deleted all my comments from here to clear the workplace. Could you do the same, please ? Anyway, I've been looking around about the transparency (before I asked on MSDN) and it seems this is what you need http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/46f1aabb-c6ca-48be-a424-944934113ef9 And the `alpha_32.avi` file you've shared is actually Uncompressed RGB32, but you need to have Uncompressed ARGB32.

Comment: The 32bit example I uploaded is an ARGB32 file. I don't know if the codec natively supports alpha but definitely has an alpha channel. Whe I import it into any video application or even Photoshop it loads the alpha channel.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the guy is talking bullshit. H.264 has never supported alpha and I haven't heared of any implentation that support alpha. H.264 is an enduser codec and those never support alpha.
Quicktime would definitely be a solution but is that even technically possible to install a whole coded and loading up the codec before showing the slpash without letting the user wait for several seconds? Besides from the fact that its not a nice to the user to just install a codec like you said before.

Comment: I checked the file with mediainfo which also said its RGBA, which means its definitely something supported nativley and not some Adobe only thing.
`ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : RGBA
Codec ID                                 : 0x00000000
Codec ID/Info                            : Basic Windows bitmap format. 1, 4 and 8 bpp versions are palettised. 16, 24 and 32bpp contain raw RGB samples`

Oh and here a link about h.264 and alpha: http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/2/987656
would be nice to have in this case but its just not possible

Comment: Oh before I forget, don't make yourself too much work with the alpha thing. Having a borderless splashscreen would already add so much to Inno :)

Comment: To get the borderless video window with current version of Inno Media Player is enough to add `VideoForm.BorderStyle := bsNone` like I did in my post update.

Comment: But back to what you've said before, you wanted to animate about 50 image files. If so, then try to check out the [`Inno Image Animator`](http://code.google.com/p/inno-image-animator/downloads/detail?name=InnoImageAnimator.zip&can=2&q=). In one function call you pass the source path, frame display time (optionaly repeat count) and you'll get the topmost window animating transparent PNG files from a given path in given frame interval. There's a demo application included. P.S. I still don't have my laptop back, so it's not so easy to maintain projects to me. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Borderless video works perfectly!
Only change I could think of is to add a failsafe feature so it just skips the video if it fails to load it for any reason. Otherwise you get a grey rectangle and the setup has to be killed with the task manager.

The image animator is awesome! Exactly what I wanted for my small animations with alpha! Can this be made bordless aswell? Seems like 100 pngs are a little too much but everything more than 50 files is an overkill anways.
Unfortunately I have a little bug when the setup gets closed: http://i.imgur.com/fEldU.jpg

Comment: I'm on my friend's computer with Windows XP SP3 now and the media player fails on unhandled exception with video files with unknown format and I have to find and fix this issue, so please don't use it yet. I have to debug the library, but can't at this time :-( To fix the grayed window see the post update. It's enough to initialize video file and show the video window at wizard initialization. When it succeeds, then in on show event play the file.

Comment: The memory leak in animator is [`now fixed`](http://code.google.com/p/inno-image-animator/downloads/detail?name=InnoImageAnimator.zip) .(and the error message supressed only for debug time). I also fixed the problem in taskbar (there was an extra taskbar button for animation form; now it's correctly *merged* with the setup's one, however now the demo won't show properly in taskbar; it's because InnoSetup doesn't provide handle to its invisible window laying on the taskbar, thus I have to find it by getting main form's owner, what doesn't work for demo app (I'll try to improve this later on).