# Video file in Inno Setup with relative path as splash screen

Tags: video, installation, inno-setup, splash-screen, pascalscript

I just saw this topic for video splash screen for Inno Setup
[Video file (with alpha) as splash-screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484388/video-file-with-alpha-as-splash-screen)

The sample code presented by @TLama (Author of Inno Media Player) is great but it has a little problem and that's this:
Splash video file that is pointed in code has absolute path like: `d:\Video.avi`

So if I want to publish my setup program to other computers absolute path like `d:\Video.avi` will not work anymore...

Therefore I am asking the author (@TLama) to revise this script and make the video file splash with relative path like: `{src}` or `{tmp}`.

---

The second revision that want to ask author is that:

I want to implement closing of the video playback by clicking the client area of a window...that is not available in above sample code...

---

My script:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Media Player Project
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Media Player Project

[Files]
Source: "MediaPlayer.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
```

```pascal
[Code]
const
  EC_COMPLETE = $01;

type
  TDirectShowEventProc = procedure(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer);

function DSPlayMediaFile: Boolean;
  external 'DSPlayMediaFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
function DSStopMediaPlay: Boolean;
  external 'DSStopMediaPlay@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
function DSInitializeVideoFile(FileName: WideString; WindowHandle: HWND;
  var Width, Height: Integer; CallbackProc: TDirectShowEventProc): Boolean;
  external 'DSInitializeVideoFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';

var
  VideoForm: TSetupForm;  

procedure OnMediaPlayerEvent(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer); 
begin
  if EventCode = EC_COMPLETE then
    VideoForm.Close;  
end;

procedure OnVideoFormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DSPlayMediaFile;
end;

procedure OnVideoFormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  DSStopMediaPlay;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Width: Integer;
  Height: Integer;
begin
  VideoForm := CreateCustomForm;
  VideoForm.Caption := 'Popup Video Window';
  VideoForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  VideoForm.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
  VideoForm.Position := poScreenCenter;
  VideoForm.OnShow := @OnVideoFormShow;
  VideoForm.OnClose := @OnVideoFormClose; 

  if DSInitializeVideoFile('d:\Video.avi', VideoForm.Handle, Width, 
    Height, @OnMediaPlayerEvent)
  then
  begin
    VideoForm.ClientWidth := Width;
    VideoForm.ClientHeight := Height;     
    VideoForm.ShowModal;
  end;    
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  DSStopMediaPlay;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just swap `'d:\video.avi'` with `ExpandConstant('{tmp}\video.avi')`, with a prior call to `ExtractTemporaryFile`.

Or if you want to distribute the video alongside the setup (eg. on DVD) rather than embedded into it, then use `{src}` instead of `{tmp}`, and skip `ExtractTemporaryFile`.

---

To the second question. There was missing the message drain which would allow the `IVideoWindow` forward keyboard and mouse messages to the window owner. In the updated version of the library the messages are dispatched to the owner, so download the latest version and add the code like this to close the video window by clicking on it:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure OnVideoFormClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  // it's enough to just close the form as it owns the IVideoWindow
  VideoForm.Close;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  VideoForm := CreateCustomForm;
  ...
  VideoForm.OnClick := @OnVideoFormClick;
  ...
end;
```