# Inno Setup - How to loop video playback with Inno Media Library

Tags: inno-setup

How to define that the medial playback callback function restarts a video playback?

I use a code from this question:
[Inno Setup - video file with relative path as splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849118/inno-setup-video-file-with-relative-path-as-splash-screen)

```pascal
procedure OnMediaPlayerEvent(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer);
begin
  if EventCode = EC_COMPLETE then
    VideoForm.Close; { not close, start again, and again.... }
end;
```

PD: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Did you try to call the `DSPlayMediaFile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a more elegant solution, but a trivial one is to simply reinitialize the video playback:

```pascal
procedure OnMediaPlayerEvent(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer); 
var
  Width: Integer;
  Height: Integer;
begin
  if EventCode = EC_COMPLETE then
  begin
    DSInitializeVideoFile(
      'd:\Video.avi', VideoForm.Handle, Width, Height, @OnMediaPlayerEvent);
    DSPlayMediaFile;  
  end;
end;
```