# Inno Setup Maximize splash video

Tags: video, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using Inno Media Player by TLama to show a splash video at the beginning of the setup.

Therefore I am using the following code:

```pascal
[Code]
const
  EC_COMPLETE = $01;

type
  TDirectShowEventProc = procedure(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer);

function DSGetLastError(var ErrorText: WideString): HRESULT;
  external 'DSGetLastError@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
function DSPlayMediaFile: Boolean;
  external 'DSPlayMediaFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
function DSStopMediaPlay: Boolean;
  external 'DSStopMediaPlay@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
function DSInitializeVideoFile(FileName: WideString; WindowHandle: HWND; var Width,
  Height: Integer; CallbackProc: TDirectShowEventProc): Boolean;
  external 'DSInitializeVideoFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';

var
  VideoForm: TSetupForm;

procedure OnMediaPlayerEvent(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer); 
begin
  if EventCode = EC_COMPLETE then
    VideoForm.Close;
end;

procedure OnVideoFormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  ErrorCode: HRESULT;
  ErrorText: WideString; 
  Width, Height: Integer;
  begin
  if DSInitializeVideoFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#MyVideo}'), VideoForm.Handle, Width, 
    Height, @OnMediaPlayerEvent) then
  begin
    VideoForm.ClientWidth := Width;
    VideoForm.ClientHeight := Height;
    DSPlayMediaFile;
  end
  else
  begin
    ErrorCode := DSGetLastError(ErrorText);
    MsgBox('TDirectShowPlayer error: ' + IntToStr(ErrorCode) + '; ' + 
      ErrorText, mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

procedure OnVideoFormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  DSStopMediaPlay;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
ExtractTemporaryFile('{#MyVideo}');

  VideoForm := CreateCustomForm;
  VideoForm.Position := poScreenCenter;
  VideoForm.OnShow := @OnVideoFormShow;
  VideoForm.OnClose := @OnVideoFormClose;
  VideoForm.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
  VideoForm.Caption := 'Popup Video Window';
  VideoForm.ShowModal;

end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  DSStopMediaPlay;
end;
```

Now I wanted to ask if there is a possibility to maximize the video window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect from that? The form is as large as the video is. Making it larger won't help anything. Do you want to scale the video with the form?

Comment: How the `VideoPanel` relates to the question?

Comment: Yes, I want to scale the video with the form. Because if I see a video with higher resolution than the screen, it will be cut off. That is the way I want to avoid this. If you have other suggestions I would be glad to hear from you. What do you exactly mean with the `videopanel`? The tag `video`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl or do you mean the `video window` of the caption? Sorry by the way, forgot the @ in the last post so I don't know if you were already notified.

Comment: I was asking about `VideoPage := CreateCustomPage` in your code. It's not in [the original code by @TLama](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11495362/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, but I found an [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15856832/5377777), where TLama informs that there is a newer version of his mediaplayer available. So the code above is of the example.iss which is included in the mediaplayer. I only changed the code to extract the video into the `temp-dir`. As far as I know the video panel is there, so that the user is able to skip the video, but I don't really need it. So I can do without it actually.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl got it now. The sample code was a bit larger, so that you were able to play a video and/or an audio file embedded in an separate created wizard page. I removed that, but I forgot to remove the code snippets you found. [Here is the full original code of the example.iss](http://pastebin.com/Vm9aqU16)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have edit the code above. It should be correct now. The difference between the old code from TLama and the new edited code is that an error message that will be shown when an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ShowWindow`](https://web.archive.org/web/20100626022052/http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=ShowWindow_%28%29) with the `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED` flag to maximize the window.

The `DSInitializeVideoFile` accepts the desired size of the video in an input value of the `Width` and `Height` parameters.

So if you display and maximize the window prior to starting the video, you can pass a size of the maximized window.

Something like:

```pascal
function ShowWindow(hWnd: DWord; nCmdShow: Integer): Boolean;
  external 'ShowWindow@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure OnVideoFormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  Width: Integer;
  Height: Integer;
  VideoForm: TForm;
begin
  VideoForm := TForm(Sender);

  ShowWindow(VideoForm.Handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);

  Width := VideoForm.ClientWidth;
  Height := VideoForm.ClientHeight;

  if not DSInitializeVideoFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#MyVideo}'), VideoForm.Handle,
    Width, Height, @OnMediaPlayerEvent) then
  begin
    VideoForm.Close;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  VideoForm := CreateCustomForm;
  ...
  VideoForm.ShowModal;
end;
```